# clearcase snapshot hijacked files : how to checkout/checkin changed files

Tags: git, performance, clearcase

Clearcase sucks a lot. It seems I cannot just save modifications to my project quickly. By quickly I mean in less than 1 second.

The solution I have found is to use the combo clearcase + git. I'm using snapshots views because I can easily hijack my files without having to checkout all the files in my project every time I want to do refactoring.

The problem is, when I play with git and navigate between new and old versions, clearcase think all the files are hijacked. Then I need to do the following.

1. cleartool update
2. cleartool ls -recurse | grep "hijacked" | xargs cleartool diff -prev [...] > changed
3. cat changed | xargs cleartool co -nc
4. cat changed | xargs cleartool ci -c 'some words...'
5. rm **/*.keep
6. git checkout .

The operation consisting of "clearcase push" which takes about 2 seconds with git will last for at least 10 minutes. I see only two explanation regarding this issue:

1. I really do not know how to use clearcase
2. Clearcase really sucks!

Does somebody knows how to quickly checkout then checkin modified hijacked files with Clearcase not UCM version ?

**Edit:**

Following the advices of [Vonc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) I made a script that uses `clearfsimport`:

```
#!/bin/bash/
OUT="$(mktemp -d)"
DST=/vob/project_root/
echo -e "\nCreating temporary folder..."
echo $OUT

echo -e "\nCopying relevant elements..."
find . | grep -E '.*?\.(c|h|inc|asm|mac|def|ldf|rst)$' | xargs -I % cp --parents % $OUT
DOUT=$(cygpath -d $OUT/*)
DDST=$(cygpath -d $DST)
echo -e "\nImporting new elements to cleacase..."
clearfsimport -rec -unco -nset $DOUT $DDST

echo -e "\nRemoving temporary files..."
rm -rf $OUT
```

The reason why I need to make a copy of my repository is that `clearfsimport` cannot directly exclude files or directories and wildcard options does not work with this tool. It takes a directory tree as is. Also I do not want to remove all my unversionned files such as object files or even the .git from my working directory.

I think I can make this script much better by identifying with git all the files that changed since the last execution of my script. Might be a bit tricky to do...

Also I can set my matching files pattern using .gitignore

Perhaps others already made such scripts...

Comment: Great script and feedback. Regarding the modified files, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/1552353/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/8016831/6309 could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sequence for updating ClearCase file from a git working tree is pretty much the "optimal" one, meaning it won't get much faster.

One alternative I have been playing with when [using ClearCase and Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309) is **[clearfsimport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070750/6309)**, with 2 ClearCase views.

- one snapshot view is for updating a set of files which are then make hijacked (for a git working tree to use)
- one snapshot (or dynamic actually) view to be the recipient, the destination of the changes done in the first working tree.

`clearfsimport` allows you to take any working tree (managed or not by ClearCase, it doesn't care), and import it in a ClearCase view ([it can be a dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309), by the way), and:

- checkout only the modified files
- leave the identical files alone
- remove / add the files in the ClearCase view, which were deleted/created in the working tree

It is a process more efficient than diff'ing everything, and it should be *much* faster.
That doesn't mean it is *fast*.
It is still, after all, **[ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074785/6309)**.

Comment: I'm confused with `clearfsimport`. It tries to check all the thousands files in my .git folder. How can I ignore .git and obj/ folders ?

Comment: @coin simply make sure the .git isn't store in a working tree you intent to import in ClearCase. Remember that `GIT_DIR` can be set up in order to reference a .git outside of a working tree. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10824664/6309

Comment: This doesn't solve the case of obj/*.o and all temp files. I made a HUGE list with wildcard. This is ugly but it seems to works...

Comment: And I agree with you "It is much faster. That doesn't mean it is fast" :(

Comment: @coin or you could do *several* clearfsimport, in order to not import the wrong subfolders.

Comment: Arf! If I use the syntax: `clearfsimport -rec -unco -nset ~/.../*.c /ccase/vob/project/` it will put all the new elements to the root of my dest folder. `...` doesn't work as I expected. Any suggestion?

Comment: @coin yes, `clearfsimport` is made to import a directory tree as is (cleaned up beforehand), not to be used as you want: cleanup first the tree structure, then you can use the `clearfsimport`. As said in the man page http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm: "For each path name, the leaf of the path name is imported into the target VOB. For example, `/usr/src/lib/foo.c` is imported into the VOB `/vobs/mylib` as `/vobs/mylib/foo.c` or into the VOB `/bigvob` as `/bigvob/foo.c`."