# Git: Copy a Group files from one Git Branch into Another Git branch?

Tags: git, devops, git-log

How can I Copy all the files, I have changed in last 10 days, from one branch, and place them into another git branch?

This locates all the files changed,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8016702/14432516

```
git log --since="10 day ago" --author="John Smith" --name-only --pretty=format: | sort | uniq
```

Now, trying to utilize answer below, to specify a Subset of files to copy into another git branch. This answer takes All the files, not a specified group.

[How can I get All the files from one git branch, and put them into the current branch without merging?](https://superuser.com/questions/692794/how-can-i-get-all-the-files-from-one-git-branch-and-put-them-into-the-current-b)

Example: Move/Copy 25 files from Git Branch A to Git Branch B, taking the files as is, Or merge (take source). Want all the files as in Branch A.

Looking for a quick automated way to conduct this for 100+ files.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307579/9210961) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2364147/9210961) may be useful. Also, look into `git filter-branch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files aren't actually in *branches*.  Files are in *commits*.  Every commit has a full and complete copy of every file, or more precisely, every file that Git knew about at the time you (or whoever) made that commit.

Why this matters is that it makes the answer easy—or rather, *mostly* easy.  We'll see more about this *mostly* part in a bit.

Given:

> This locates all the files [I want to copy]:
>
> `git log arguments --name-only | sort -u`

you can now simply copy those files from the *last* commit in the sequence of commits that `git log` examined.  Since the specified *`arguments`* above didn't include any specific commit, Git started from the commit that was the `HEAD` commit at that time, which would be the tip commit of the branch you had checked out at that time.  For instance, let's say you had branch `branch-A` out.

You might also want to, at this point, do:
arguments="--since="10 day ago" --author="John Smith" --name-only --pretty=format:"
files=$(git log $arguments | sort -u)
echo $files

(The only reason for setting `$arguments` first is to make all this fit on one line in this posting, and/or to let you run `git log` like this more than once.)

> [How do I get (those files) ready to be committed into a new commit I will make on `branch-B`?]

You'd next run:

```
git checkout branch-B
```

as usual.  Then, as in [the better answer to the question you linked](https://superuser.com/a/1431858/941003), you would use:

```
git checkout branch-A -- $files
```

The `$files` variable is set from the output from the `git log --name-only | sort -u` command.

#### Mostly

Where the *mostly* comes in is that `$files` can have two problems:

1. Some of the file names might contain spaces.  Shells such as `bash`—the examples here are all sh / dash / bash compatible—treat spaces as breaking up arguments, which is why you can run `git log --since=...` in the first place: each of those `log`, `--since`, `--name-only`, and so on have to be passed to the Git command as separate arguments.

   But suppose that you have a file named `path/to/file with spaces.ext`.  Then `$files` contains `path/to/file with spaces.ext`, which to bash, looks like you typed in `path/to/file` as one argument, `with` as a second argument, and `spaces.ext` as a third argument.

   If you *are* stuck with this situation, bash in particular has some ways to deal with it.  Your best bet is to avoid spaces in file names in the first place, though.
2. It's possible that one of the activities on some file, that `git log` showed you above, is that the file got *deleted* in that commit.  The `--name-only` option tells Git to show you only the *names* of files that had some change made, between the parent of the commit and the commit in question.  If the change-made was "delete the file entirely", that file *isn't* in the *new* commit, and probably isn't in the final commit either, because it probably stayed deleted.

   The right thing to do for such a file is generally to leave it deleted.  So if you get an error about this file, just take it out of the `$files` set: it's not in the commit at the tip of `branch_A` so you can't *copy it out* of that commit, but you don't *want* to copy it out anyway.  Just leave it deleted.

Note that instead of `git checkout` above, you can use `git restore` if your Git is 2.23 or later.<sup>1</sup>  This isn't any *better* than `git checkout`, it's just a little *clearer:* the `git checkout` command in Git versions predating 2.23 can do one of several jobs, and in Git 2.23, those jobs were subdivided into two separate commands: `git switch` does about half of them, and `git restore` does the other roughly-half of those jobs.

(Having split the command into two, the split-up commands were then made *smarter* and *better*.  So in the current versions of Git, as time goes on, `git switch` and `git restore` put together can do *more* than `git checkout`.  The old `git checkout` continues to exist so that if you are used to it, you can keep using it.  If you need some of the new abilities, though, you must switch to the new commands.)

---

<sup>1</sup>When using `git restore`, you'll want `git restore --source=branch_A -iw -- $files`, rather than `git checkout branch_A -- $files`.  This is a little longer to type in, which can be annoying, but it has the same effect.  The "smarter-ness" of `git restore` is that you can select whether the files go into Git's index or not, and whether they go into your working tree or not, individually.

Comment: thanks this is helpful, however looking for an Automated way, to take my list of files in first command, and copy them in, if possible

Comment: Turn the above into a script. To bullet-proof the space issues, use `git log`'s `-z` option and write the list of files to a file, or use a language like Python to read them out (Python allows you to handle the sorting more directly). Consider also using `--name-status` and/or `diff-filter` to handle additional cases, such as deleted and renamed files.

Comment: I literally just copied the 20 file list into excel, added "git checkout branch a" as a prefix,   and then took the new excel list in gitbash, and copied and pasted, it worked ! thanks

Comment: thanks, accepted answer, and also provided another subset answer